# What is the probability distribution of the net payoff of my sports bets?

Tags: probability

I am placing 6 sportsbets this weekend each with a probability of 50% of winning and 50% of losing.

I would like to know how to figure out the probability of the following outcomes:

a) winning 0 bets
b) winning 1 bet
c) winning 2 bets
d) winning 3 bets
e) winning 4 bets
f) winning 5 bets
g) winning 6 bets

I can figure out that 0 and 6 are both the same at 1/64 or 1.56% and that winning 3 is 50%.  Is this right and how do I figure out the others?

Answer (score 3):

There are exactly
$$\binom 6n = \frac{6!}{n!(6 - n)!}$$
combinations of $n$ elements chosen from the $6$ total elements. As you already noted, there are in total $2^6 = 64$ combinations.

Assuming that each bet is independent from each other, it follows that the probability of winning $n$ bets is
$$p(n) = \binom 6n \left(\frac12\right)^6.$$

So we have that
$$\begin{align}
p(0) = p(6) = \frac1{64}\\[0.6em]
p(1) = p(5) = \frac3{32}\\[0.6em]
p(2) = p(4) = \frac{15}{64}\\[0.6em]
p(3) = \frac{20}{64} = \frac5{16}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think it's worth noting here that you assume each bet is independent form each other.

Comment: @SRKX You're right, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the $6$th row in *Pascal Triangle*:

$$\binom60,\binom61,\binom62,\binom63,\binom64,\binom65,\binom66$$

Or equivalently:

$$1,6,15,20,15,6,1$$

Your probabilities are:

$$\frac{\binom60}{2^6},\frac{\binom61}{2^6},\frac{\binom62}{2^6},\frac{\binom63}{2^6},\frac{\binom64}{2^6},\frac{\binom65}{2^6},\frac{\binom66}{2^6}$$

Or equivalently:

$$\frac{1}{64},\frac{6}{64},\frac{15}{64},\frac{20}{64},\frac{15}{64},\frac{6}{64},\frac{1}{64}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of winning exactly three bets is $${6\choose 3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6=\frac{20}{64}=31.25\%$$

In this expression ${6\choose 3}$ is a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) that counts how many ways there are to choose which three of the six bets you win.